# How can remove multiple playlist items on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPy4P.png) I have an api that loads 10 items from a Jasonfile When i click the mehr(more) button. If clicked again, it loads 10 more and so on... In the JPlayer [documentation](http://%20http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/), they only show how to remove 1 item at a time:

```
  myPlaylist.remove(); // Removes all items
  myPlaylist.remove(0); // Removes the 1st item
  myPlaylist.remove(1); // Removes the 2nd item
  myPlaylist.remove(-1); // Removes the last item
```

Is it possible to remove 10 items at once when i click the weniger(less) button? I tried this:

```
$(".pc-less-btn.btn-{{ pk }}").click(function() {
  myPlaylist.remove(10); // To Removes 10 items but doesn't works
});
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation it don't look like you can remove a range of playlist items. You can make a simple loop inside your click and use that

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: set new playlist

```
$(".pc-less-btn.btn-{{ pk }}").click(function() {
  const removeFromIndex = 10
  // remove from end
  const newPlaylist = myPlaylist.playlist.slice(myPlaylist.playlist.length - removeFromIndex)
  // remove from start
  // const newPlaylist = myPlaylist.playlist.slice(removeFromIndex)
  myPlaylist.setPlaylist(newPlaylist)
});
```

Option 2: remove one by one (Not recommended)

```
$(".pc-less-btn.btn-{{ pk }}").click(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myPlaylist.remove(i); // indexes of playlist probably changes
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @medet thanks for the quick answer. But it removes 10 and add 10 again

Comment: it shouldn't add, play with removeFromIndex values, probably you removing more than adding?

Comment: It does when i use remove from end. but when i use remove from start it doesn't add.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tricky solution. I wanted to remove all the items from the playlist so I was looking for the solution so I found this trick so far it works for me. I've tested in version 2.9.2

Suppose your playlist object is `player` so on any jQuery click event you can get your selected list indexes like this

```
$("#selector_id").on("click", function (e) {
    var object = $(this);
    var ids = []; // Fetch you ids in your way, either checkbox or anything or manual enter

    // Then get the playlist from the player object.
    var playlist = player.playlist;
    // Check if playlist has data.
    if (playlist && playlist.length) {
        var new_playlist = [];
        $.each(playlist, function (index, item) {
            // If index is not in your ids then get the playlist item.
            if (!ids.includes(index)) {
                new_playlist.push(item);
            }
        });

        // Now you have new playlist after removing selected items.
        // Check if we have anything in new playlist.
        if (new_playlist.length) {
            // If we have data in new playlist then init playlist.
            player._initPlaylist(new_playlist);
            // Then call the refresh function with clearMedia event.
            player._refresh(function () {
                $(player.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("clearMedia");
            });

            // You can call update Control if you have Controls enabled.
        }
    }
});
```